# The loop within my script is iterating incorrectly

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have written a loop for a college project in JavaScript, for setting the style value for multiple elements:

```
for (var i=1; i<6; i++) {
    document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes[i].style.display =
    "block";
}
```

My problem is that the loop only iterates twice, evidenced by alerting the value of 'i'; rather than the desired five times.

However, with the statement within the loop commented out, the loop does iterate the correct amount of times, and so I am assuming there is an issue with the statement that would cause the loop to behave so bizarrely...

Any replies/suggestions would be much appreciated

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the speedy replies, here is the profile_details element, showing that there is more than 3 child elements:

```
    <ul id="profile_details">
        <li>Artist</li>
        <li style="display:none;">Address: </li>
        <li style="display:none;">City: </li>
        <li style="display:none;">Postcode: </li>
        <li style="display:none;">Telephone: </li>
        <li style="display:none;">Website: </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Side note: perform `var someVar = document.getElementById("profile_details")` ONCE outside of the loop, then loop through `someVar.childNodes[i]` inside.

Comment: Without more information childNodes[3] is likely undefined causing a Javascript error.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only have 3 `childNodes` in `#profile_details`, so you get a TypeError when trying to access `style` of `undefined`.

You should be seeing this in your console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

---

You should first check how many children it has, then set your loop to that amount:

```
var children = document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes;

for (var i = 1, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
    children [i].style.display = "block";
}
```

This'll affect all the children, except for the first one. If you also want the first one to be affected by this, you should start your counter from 0: `var i = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `profile_details` element has at least 5 children? You should probably be doing this instead, for both performance and to work correctly:

```
var profileDetailsChildren = document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes;
for (var i=0; i<profileDetailsChildren.length; i++) {
    profileDetailsChildren[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How many child nodes does the element have? (`document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes.length` will tell you). Most likely there are only 3. Trying to access an array element that doesn't exist gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many child nodes your element has, you can iterate like this:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes;
for (var i=1; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Just to be sure, also notice, that the first element in `elems` is `elems[0]`, (or maybe you needed to leave the first element out of iteration).

---

**EDIT**

Newer browsers include also all characters between tags (including white-space characters and newlines) to the `childNodes` collection as a `textNode`. However, these `textNode`s don't have `style` property, hence the browser throws an error and your loop fails. You need to check, if the type of the current node is valid for styling:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("profile_details").childNodes;
for (var i=1; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].nodeType === 1) {
        elems[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to use `children` collection, which doesn't contain `textNode`s:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("profile_details").children;
```

**A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuGC9/)**